# problem during distribution upgrade to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 23.04, 23.10

I run xubuntu and yesterday i try to upgrade 23.04 to 23.10.But I had a lot of errors like :

```
243 2023-11-06 19:04:19,660 DEBUG got a conffile-prompt from dpkg for file: '/etc/systemd/journald.conf'
244 2023-11-06 19:27:05,971 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'udev': 'le sous-processus paquet udev script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1'
245 2023-11-06 19:27:05,973 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() udev: le sous-processus paquet udev script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1
246 2023-11-06 19:27:06,007 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'udev': 'le sous-processus paquet udev script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1'
247 2023-11-06 19:27:25,571 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'systemd-hwe-hwdb': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
248 2023-11-06 19:27:25,571 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() systemd-hwe-hwdb: problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
249 2023-11-06 19:27:25,572 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against systemd-hwe-hwdb
250 2023-11-06 19:27:25,572 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'systemd-hwe-hwdb': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
251 2023-11-06 19:30:36,818 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'initramfs-tools-core': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
252 2023-11-06 19:30:36,818 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() initramfs-tools-core: problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
253 2023-11-06 19:30:36,818 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against initramfs-tools-core
254 2023-11-06 19:30:36,818 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'initramfs-tools-core': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
255 2023-11-06 19:30:42,234 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'snapd': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
256 2023-11-06 19:30:42,234 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() snapd: problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
257 2023-11-06 19:30:42,234 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against snapd
258 2023-11-06 19:30:42,234 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'snapd': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
....
438 2023-11-06 20:14:01,805 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'rtkit': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
439 2023-11-06 20:14:01,806 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() rtkit: problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
440 2023-11-06 20:14:01,806 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against rtkit
441 2023-11-06 20:14:01,806 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'rtkit': 'problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré'
442 2023-11-06 20:15:03,060 ERROR Exception during pm.DoInstall()
443 Traceback (most recent call last):
444   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-n0kzpqbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 220, in run
445     res = pm.do_install(self.writefd)
446           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
447 apt_pkg.Error: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
448 2023-11-06 20:15:03,098 ERROR SystemError from cache.commit(): installArchives() failed
449 2023-11-06 20:15:03,098 ERROR found exception: 'E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'
450 2023-11-06 20:32:23,904 WARNING ctrl-c press detected, user decided to pass it on: False
451 2023-11-06 21:12:32,182 DEBUG Running PostInstallScript: './xorg_fix_proprietary.py'
452 2023-11-06 21:12:32,189 ERROR got error from PostInstallScript ./xorg_fix_proprietary.py (g-io-error-quark: Impossible d’exécuter le processus fils « ./xorg_fix_proprietary.py » : Failed     to execve: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (1))
453 2023-11-06 21:12:32,189 DEBUG Running PostInstallScript: '/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/upgrade_lts_contract.py'
```

but at the end, I restarted and a lsb-release -a said :

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
```

**EDIT :**

In /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-term.log i found a lot of failed just after replacing journald.conf :

```
    Paramétrage de systemd (253.5-1ubuntu6) ...
Fichier de configuration « /etc/systemd/journald.conf »
 ==> Modifié (par vous ou par un script) depuis l'installation.
 ==> Le distributeur du paquet a fourni une version mise à jour.
   Que voulez-vous faire ? Vos options sont les suivantes :
    Y ou I  : installer la version du responsable du paquet
    N ou O  : garder votre version actuellement installée
      D     : afficher les différences entre les versions
      Z     : suspendre ce processus pour examiner la situation
 L'action par défaut garde votre version actuelle.
*** journald.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [défaut=N] ? y
Installation de la nouvelle version du fichier de configuration /etc/systemd/journald.conf ...
Installation de la nouvelle version du fichier de configuration /etc/systemd/sleep.conf ...
Installation de la nouvelle version du fichier de configuration /etc/systemd/system.conf ...
Installation de la nouvelle version du fichier de configuration /etc/systemd/user.conf ...
Failed to try-restart systemd-networkd.service: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-networkd.service' for details.
Failed to try-restart systemd-journald.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-journald.service' for details.
    .......
Failed to try-restart systemd-journald.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop ubuntu-advantage.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop ua-timer.timer: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop NetworkManager-wait-online.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop nm-priv-helper.service: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
    Failed to stop plocate-updatedb.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop plocate-updatedb.timer: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to stop rtkit-daemon.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to get unit file state for anacron.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to retrieve unit state: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to get unit file state for anacron.timer: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to retrieve unit state: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
    Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to get unit file state for dmesg.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
    Failed to retrieve unit state: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

In syslog I found that differents errors on dbus-daemon :

```
dbus-daemon[679]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
4966 2023-11-06T19:08:29.996872+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[679]: [system] Reloaded configuration
4967 2023-11-06T19:08:29.997908+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB cups-browsed[5805]: WARNING: Unhandled message: interface=org.freedesktop.DBus, path=/org/freedesktop/DBus, member=ActivatableSer     vicesChanged
4968 2023-11-06T19:08:30.003161+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[679]: Unknown username "polkitd" in message bus configuration file
4969 2023-11-06T19:08:30.003534+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[679]: Unknown username "polkitd" in message bus configuration file
4970 2023-11-06T19:08:30.012900+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[679]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
4971 2023-11-06T19:08:30.016452+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[679]: [system] Reloaded configuration
4972 2023-11-06T19:08:30.016580+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB cups-browsed[5805]: WARNING: Unhandled message: interface=org.freedesktop.DBus, path=/org/freedesktop/DBus, member=ActivatableServicesChanged
```

and if i look for error at 19:27 to refer to the log i found in main.log

```
5619 2023-11-06T19:27:06.159082+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB avahi-daemon[676]: Files changed, reloading.
5620 2023-11-06T19:27:06.159877+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB avahi-daemon[676]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
5621 2023-11-06T19:27:06.276519+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36160]: The home dir /var/lib/avahi-autoipd you specified already exists.
5622 2023-11-06T19:27:06.284520+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36160]: The system user `avahi-autoipd' already exists. Exiting.
5623 2023-11-06T19:27:11.038844+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36198]: Selecting UID from range 100 to 999 ...
5624 2023-11-06T19:27:11.045641+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36198]: Adding system user `dhcpcd' (UID 128) ...
5625 2023-11-06T19:27:11.049825+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36198]: Adding new user `dhcpcd' (UID 128) with group `nogroup' ...
5626 2023-11-06T19:27:11.214300+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB adduser[36198]: Not creating home directory `/usr/lib/dhcpcd'.
5627 2023-11-06T19:27:37.825607+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[1804]: [session uid=1000 pid=1804] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1' uni     t='tumblerd.service' requested by ':1.26' (uid=1000 pid=2116 comm="Thunar --daemon" label="unconfined")
5628 2023-11-06T19:27:37.852517+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB systemd[1781]: Starting tumblerd.service - Thumbnailing service...
5629 2023-11-06T19:27:37.855149+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB kernel: [ 3047.412905] systemd-journald[228]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected5630 2023-11-06T19:27:37.940885+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB dbus-daemon[1804]: [session uid=1000 pid=1804] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.thumbnails.Thumbnailer1'
5631 2023-11-06T19:27:37.941918+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB systemd[1781]: Started tumblerd.service - Thumbnailing service.
5632 2023-11-06T19:28:03.495194+01:00 Lenovoideapad320S14IKB kernel: [ 3073.052430] systemd-journald[228]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

nothing in journald and If I try to relaunch do-release-upgrade it says

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Recherche d'une nouvelle version d'Ubuntu
Aucune nouvelle version n'a été trouvée.
```

The problem is my pc doesn't seem to be as clean as before. For exemple when i copy a large file, i have not the progress bar anymore. How can i relaunch the distribution upgrade to be sure to have a clean version ?

thank you very much